# create ftp account in plesk using php

Tags: php, ftp, plesk

i will create ftp account in plesk using php that ever user register in site can have an ftp account with his username and password .
i found many php api for cpanel but in plesk i can't find any thing ? can you help me ?

thank you so a lot before !

Answer (score 1):

FTP user creation in Plesk Via SSH

http://ryanjbonnell.com/journal/ftp-account

Comment: my server is windows server 2003 . can i use this article for windows server ?

Comment: there are no solution for plesk on windows 2003 ?

Answer (score 0):

I only run Plesk on CentOS, but there should be a similar directory on the Windows side.  That being said, here's where I'd look - /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin.  The filename I use is "ftpmng".  Maybe search in the PSA directory for that.  Here's what I get for help docs on that:

```
Usage: ftpmng [OPTIONS]...

  --reconfigure-all
        create configuration files for all domains
  --reconfigure --vhost-name=<domain_name>

  --set-disk-quota --vhost-name=<domain_name> --quota=<quota>

  --get-disk-usage --vhost-name=<domain_name>

  --update-user --user-name=<user_name>

  --remove-user --user-name=<user_name>

  --kill-proftpd-process --user-name=<user_name> --pid=<pid>

  --features
        returns PHP code which reflects state of several features support in ftpmng.
  -h, --help
        display this help and exit
```

Answer (score 0):

please confirm what plesk version you used.

Normally, plesk provides the xml-rpc API for Developer, easily can create ftp and many others with php,java, c#.

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc-guide/

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/